# Semantic div structures vs styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to have a background "frame", but it is only meant for styling. I want to accomplish this without using bg-image just to avoid having an image, but my concern is that having an additional parent element to the "picture" seems to be unnecessary. What is the best way to go about this? The frame basically just has additional padding and border.

--
I want the inner div to have drop shadow and a border, and the other div to have another border with a variable padding in between. is that possible with styling on a single div?

Comment: And why can't you add the padding and border with CSS?

Comment: I want the inner div to have drop shadow and a border, and the other div to have another border with a variable padding in between. is that possible with styling on a single div?

Comment: Hard to say, I can't visualize it.  Can you create a mockup image of what you mean?

Comment: what does javascript, jquery and html5 has to do with your question?

Comment: ok let me add on to my question: can this be accomplished by any of the technologies listed in the tags?

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/542/whatimean.png/

Comment: That is why there is background-image property. You can have a div#container after the body element and set it using the background-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Z82Sv/

If so, that's your answer.

[edit]: to clarify, you can do all kinds of things with this, such as http://jsfiddle.net/Z82Sv/1/

Comment: Dude, that is just a blue box?

Comment: He just wanted a frame, right? He can put anything he wants in place of the blue.